# Hover rule for keywords in XText

Tags: dsl, xtext

I was wondering if XText supports hover information for keywords (rules). So far I have only seen examples for instances of those, never for the keyword as such.

To outline here is a small sample of what I have in mind.

```
/**
 * use: login (username, password) 
 */
Login: 'login' ('('username=STRING ',' password=STRING ')' )?;
```

In the Editor I would then expect to see "use: login (username, password)" when I hover over "login", the highlighted keyword. Ideally one could use a Javadoc style of comment, but any other solution is welcome.

Comment: Some good options can be found here http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/452862/1008201/#msg_1008201 One of them is explained here http://blogs.itemis.de/stundzig/archives/868